# Search for strings in large array takes a long time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, searchbar

I'm implementing a search field that filters a UITableView according to the text the user enters.
The TableView is built from an array that holds NSStrings (the data to display and search) and may contain **6000+ items**.
When the user starts the search, I'm implementing the `-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText` method.

My code works, however, when the data array is large, it is very slow and creating a really bad user experience (my iPhone 4s get stuck for a good few seconds).

The way I'm implementing the search (in the method mentioned above) is this:

```
NSMutableArray *discardedItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // Items to be removed
searchResultsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:containerArray]; // The array that holds all the data

// Search for matching results
for (int i=0; i<[searchResultsArray count]; i++) {   
    NSString *data = [[containerArray objectAtIndex:i] lowercaseString];
    NSRange r = [data rangeOfString:searchText];
    if (r.location == NSNotFound) {
        // Mark the items to be removed
        [discardedItems addObject:[searchResultsArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
// update the display array
[searchResultsArray removeObjectsInArray:discardedItems];
[myTableView reloadData];
```

I did not think that looping over an array with a few thousand items would cause any issue...
**Any suggestion will be appreciated!**

**UPDATE**
I've just realized that what takes most of the time is this:

```
[searchResultsArray removeObjectsInArray:discardedItems];
```

Comment: have you tried sorting then using binary search ?

Comment: Sorting is not possible because: 1. I need the results to be ordered according to their original order in the array. 2. I'm looking for a substring in each item in the array, not the string that it starts with. So, sorting won't help...

Comment: You're basically doing a "full text search", which is not going to be blazingly efficient in any case, unless you have some sort of pre-built index.  And, as Mientus suggests, you need to avoid creating objects (the lowercased string) in the loop.  This is especially bad since the heap fills up with these discarded strings (something you could avoid with an `autorelease` range inside the loop, though that would add its own costs).  Better to use the case-insensitive compare or have a pre-lowered version of your text.

Comment: BTW, how long is the typical string entry in your list, and how long is the typical search argument?

Comment: (Of course, the other thing you can do is throw up a "swirly" while searching, to let the user know that something is going on and the app is not simply hung.)

Comment: Typical string entry is about 15 chars long. Typical search argument - about 4 chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fast enumeration way, my snippet:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text
{
    if(text.length == 0)
    {
        self.isFiltered = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        self.isFiltered = YES;
        self.searchArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.places.count];

        for (PTGPlace* place in self.places)
        {
            NSRange nameRange = [place.name rangeOfString:text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

            if(nameRange.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [self.searchArray addObject:place];
            }
        }
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(self.isFiltered)
        return self.searchArray.count;
    else
        return self.places.count;
}
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
    PTGPlace *place = nil;

    if(self.isFiltered)
        place = [self.searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    else
        place = [self.places objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = place.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [place subtitle];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but you did exactly what I did. The only difference is that you checked the text length at the beginning - something I'm already doing in my code (but did not add to my example).

Comment: @CodeMonkey this is not at all the same as yours. the problem is how you *compare*. mientus' implementation performs a case-insensitive comparison of the strings, rather than creating thousands of temporary lowercase strings and then searching. autorelease growth and temporary string creation are the biggest time and memory consumers in your implementation. mientus' implementation creates no temporary strings, and has low autorelease activity. i wrote up a version which is too similar to post -- the approach mientus and I took was 3x faster than yours (for the input i tested). ++improved

Comment: @CodeMonkey iow - fast enumeration is not the big gain using this approach -- it is the reduction in autorelease activity, and avoiding creating many temporary strings -- just search the existing strings without creating intermediate (and unnecessary) representations.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification justin and sorry for missing the point @mientus. I'll check it out and update.

Comment: @justin, I've tried what you and mientus mentioned. I don't see any significant improvement. Please correct me if I'm wrong but you are referring to this line 'NSRange nameRange = [place.name rangeOfString:text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];' Right? I've removed all the instantiations of temporary strings, I'm using the options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch but still - the same issue remains...

Comment: @CodeMonkey right - you use `rangeOfString:options:`, but the other important step is that you will *no longer need to create a temporary `lowercaseString` representation*. have you also removed that part?

Comment: @CodeMonkey -- I'm not sure I believe that you implemented the critical changes, if you say there's no significant difference from before.

Comment: I made these exact changes. I did not test the performance before, I know it is pretty bad right now (with the critical changes)

Comment: I just realized that the problem is with removing the filtered results from the array and not the search itself.

Comment: I didn't see this before but mutable arrays in objc are slow, so if you wanted to remove couple of object from 6000object array it took few seconds.. ;)

Comment: To solve the problem - I replaced the "discardedItems" array (from my example) with 'NSMutableIndexSet *discardedItems = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet]; // Items to be removed'  I added each item's index to be removed - '[discardedItems addIndex:i];' and at the end removed the elements by - '[searchResultsArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:discardedItems];' Now it works instantly!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

for the first three positions, create 26 index sets, each representing the array index of items with that letter (just lower case). That is, say a entry at idx=100 starts with "formula". The index set representing "f" in the first position will contain the index "100". The index set for the second character 'o' will contain the index 100, and the index set for the third character 'r' will contain 100.

When the user types the character 'f', you immediately have the index set of all array items starting with 'f' (and can create a subset of your major array quickly). When an 'o' is typed next, you can find the intersection of indexes in the first match with the second match. Ditto for the third. Now make a subarray of the major array that had the first three indexes match - you can just use the index sets for this.

Using this drastically reduced array, you can now do brute force matching as you were doing originally.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm not sure I fully follow you...
It sounds like it would be better to have some sort of dictionary to hold the data or even 3 dimensional array etc.
Still, the solution is not good enough because I'm looking for substring out of the strings in the array. It not necessarily starts with the substring I'm using to search...

Comment: I just realized that the problem is with the removal from the Array and not the search itself...